# Error while updating file into mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, hive

i am trying to load csv data file into mysql , which later on i need to pass to HDFS but while updating the file

```
mysql > load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/online_retail.csv' into table retail fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 lines;
```

> ERROR : "Incorrect date value: '12/1/2010 8:26' for column
>   'invoicedate' at row 1"

```
mysql> DESCRIBE  retail;

 +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra | 
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| InvoiceNo   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| stockcode   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Description | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Quantity    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| invoicedate | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| UnitPrice   | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| CustomerId  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Country     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: The formatting of your question is in such a mess that I don't even know how to edit it.  Please take a few moments and fix your formatting so that we may read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the data type as "DATE", Date format should be in the form of "YYYY-MM-DD" or "YY-MM-DD".
Either make the data type as STRING, or transform the data to the YYYY-MM-DD format...

I.e from 12/1/2010 8:26 to 2010/12/01
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As said eggyal and as documented under [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.

And for your specific case, a few lines below :

> MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or `'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation
>     character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time
>     parts. For example, `'2012-12-31 11:30:45'`, `'2012^12^31 11+30+45'`,
>     `'2012/12/31 11*30*45'`, and `'2012@12@31 11^30^45'` are equivalent.
> - The only delimiter recognized between a date and time part and a fractional seconds part is the decimal point.
> - The date and time parts can be separated by T rather than a space. For example, `'2012-12-31 11:30:45'` `'2012-12-31T11:30:45'` are
>     equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'` or `'YYMMDDHHMMSS'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
>     For example, `'20070523091528'` and `'070523091528'` are interpreted as
>     `'2007-05-23 09:15:28'`, but `'071122129015'` is illegal (it has a
>     nonsensical minute part) and becomes `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` or `YYMMDDHHMMSS` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example,
>     `19830905132800` and `830905132800` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05 13:28:00'`

.

Therefore your expression is not a valid MySQL neither a date nor a timestamp literal. In order to comply with one of the literal formats detailed above, you must either create a script that makes your time data comply with the DATETIME or TIMESTAMP format and probably update your database to change the invoicedate type.

Comment: create table Retails( InvoiceNo int, StockCode varchar(20),description VARCHAR(500), Quantity int,InvoiceDate date, UnitPrice double,CustomerId int,Country varchar(30)); 

>>>Load the data in table

LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/online_retail.csv'  IGNORE INTO TABLE retail FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES (InvoiceNo,stockcode,Description,Quantity,@invoicedate,UnitPrice,CustomerId,Country)SET invoicedate= STR_TO_DATE(@invoicedate,'%e/%c/%Y %k:%i');

Comment: @SWAPNILKUMAR16MCB1019, I'm not sure I get it? Is it a new question?